# Ruby TCPSocket for iOS App

Tags: ruby, http, tcpsocket

I'm working on a project that requires communication between an iPhone app and a server. For my purposes, I've launched an EC2 server with Amazon Web Services. I'm trying to enable HTTP communications between the server and the iPhone in order to make requests that can be processed off the phone. Right now I am testing with a ruby client and ruby code on the server side. My server side code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'aws-sdk'
require 'socket'
require 'net/http'


server = TCPServer.open(2000)

loop {
  Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
    puts 'Time requested on client side'
    lines = []
    while line = client.gets and line !~/^\s*$/
      lines << line.chomp
      for line in lines
        puts line
      end
    end

    #socket.print(Time.now.ctime)
    client.puts(Time.now.ctime)
    client.puts 'Closing connection'
    client.close
  end
}
```

The code can print the data sent from the client, but both the client and the server get hung up when trying to send data the other way. Do communication channels need to be closed before they are reopened to send data the other way. I've been googling for about an hour and have gotten no where, even from similar questions here. On another note, is this the best way to go about doing requests or should I be using something else?

Comment: Sockets are bi-directional by nature. You might need to flush your output before closing the connection, though, or it might be stuck in the buffer.

Comment: Using plain sockets is fine for trivial tests like this, but will be increasingly difficult to use at scale. You might want to try using [eventmachine](http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org) to write the server component as it makes managing a very large number of connections a lot easier.